# Can't install SQL Profiler, it's greyed out in the feature selection list

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server

I got a problem when trying to install Management Tools - Complete on my MSSQL 2008 R2. At the Feature selection screen the Management Tools - Complete is greyed out and can't be interacted with. In the description pane here's what it says

> This feature is disabled because the parent feature was installed by a different edition of SQL Server. To install this feature upgrade the SQL Server edition of the parent feature by running the SQL Server 2008 Edition Upgrade Wizard. Screenshot provided with this hyperlink:

[Screenshot](http://i584.photobucket.com/albums/ss289/rebornedone_bucket/SQLproblem.jpg)

The hick behind all this is when we try to run the SQL Server 2008 Edition Upgrade Wizard, it tells us there is nothing that need upgrading.

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such cases happens when you first install SQL EXPESS (which include SSMS -basic only), then you install higher edition.

Basically you should use "New SQL...or add feature.." from installer menu but as you had mentioned this won't work.

Simplest solution, which requires only minutes is to uninstall MSSSMS and re-install it via the first option... this will do.